# Rails controller tests: "Filter chain halted" never appears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, before-filter

In development, my Rails log shows `Filter chain halted` when some `before_action` filter is unsatisfied, but when I run controller tests in rspec, I don't get any such information in the log.

Setting up controller tests can be a slow process in the application on which I'm working because there is an enormous legacy of `before_action` filters and a lack of test coverage. Usually, some of these filters are unsatisified when I start to write new controller tests, and I'd like to easily see which ones by checking my `log/test.log`, but it gives no insight, even when `Rails.logger.level` is `:debug`.

Is there a way for me to get this information in the log or in the controller test?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your ancient app is skipping before_actions in test to speed them up?

The two steps I would take:

- write request tests instead of controller tests
- consider adding a prepend_before_action that fires up the debugger and step through to see what's getting called

The second one is where you're really going to learn something.  If it doesn't get called then something has been shorted out.  If it does get called then you should be able to step up and through the rest of the callbacks and see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. I know that the before_actions aren't being skipped because I can monkey patch to output the filter information for each filter that's executed. There are over 100 of them, so using a debugger to go through isn't desirable when weighed against just looking at the logfile.

Comment: Then it seems like you want to monkey logger.log with a breakpoint and see where it's going!

Comment: Yes, I know how to debug the problem, but the process for debugging this way is tedious. I'd like to have the "Filter chain halted" message appear in the test log. That's ultimately my question.